# How to import a package from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

In one of my directories I have all .java files which belong to one package ("game"). Now I want to create one .java file which does not belong to this package and which imports the "game" package. If I create a new file and write `import game;` then Eclipse complains that it does not know what the "game" package means. Can somebody please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Eclipse helps you importing dependencies by pressing Ctrl+Shift+O ("organize imports")

Answer (score 20):

You cannot import a package, you need to import classes from that package:

```
import game.SomeClass;
import game.SomeOtherClass;
```

or

```
import game.*;
```

to import all classes from that package.

Eclipse can generate these imports for you if you type the class-names in your code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for Code-Completion. Select the correct class there (if more classes with the same name exist in different packages), and the import will be generated.

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to use Eclipse's 'Organize imports' shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + O.

This will find all missing types and add the appropriate imports automatically.

Answer (score -1):

import your package in your new java file or create object and get tha java class wat u want from your old package